# Nest JS Class Validator Array of Integers

Tags: nestjs, class-decorator

I am trying validate that a parameter being sent in nest js is an array of integers. The below works if I get rid of @IsInt({ each: true }), however it allows for decimals as well.

I've tried type: Int32Array and that does not work either.

```
export class SearchRequest {
  @IsArray()
  @IsInt({ each: true })
  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'The ids used to perform the search.',
    type: [Number],
    example: [13245, 54321],
  })
  ids: number[];
}
```

Using the above code, I get this error in swagger despite passing in integers:

```
{
  "message": [
    "each value in ids must be an integer number"
  ],
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "statusCode": 400
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get rid of `@IsArray()` instead of `@IsInt({ each: true })` because the `each` flag indicates that `ids` is an array and every element has to be an integer:

```
export interface ValidationOptions {
    /**
     * Specifies if validated value is an array and each of its items must be validated.
     */
    each?: boolean;
```

So this code should work:

```
export class SearchRequest {
  @IsInt({ each: true })
  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'The ids used to perform the search.',
    type: [Number],
    example: [13245, 54321],
  })
  ids: number[];
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is I still get this error in swagger, despite the fact that I'm passing only integers: 
{
  "message": [
    "each value in ids must be an integer number"
  ],
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "statusCode": 400
}

Comment: Not sure why you are getting that error, I tested it thoroughly with Swagger and directly with Curl, and it worked well for me. Could you add the code from the controller?

Comment: The only time I got that error you mentioned is when I passed an array element as string instead of an integer, for example: {
  "ids": [
    "1",
    54321
  ]
} would fail because the first element is a string. Is this your case? Could you add the request you're using in Swagger?

Comment: Ya I don't know why it wouldn't recognize that my array elements were ints, works if I go with a solution that doesn't require an array, so I'm going with that. Thanks for your help.